# How to generate/create multiple records for a related model using fakers in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to generate 10 product associated to one user. How do I do that using fakers in Laravel? Here is my model:

user Model:

```php
    class User 
    {
        public function product()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
        }
    }
```

Product Model:

```php
    class Product
    {
        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584272/how-to-seed-multiple-relationships-in-laravel-with-faker Check out this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to seed multiple relationships in Laravel with Faker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584272/how-to-seed-multiple-relationships-in-laravel-with-faker)

Answer (score 3):

I would create a ProductFactory using `php artisan make:factory ProductFactory` this should create you a class with something like this:

```php
$factory->define(Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        //
    ];
});
```

within the array to be returned you can assign your attributes, for example:

```php
$factory->define(Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'description' => $faker->text,
    ];
});
```

Then, to create multiple products assigned to that user you can do this.

```php
//assuming you have the user instance in the $user variable

$user->products()->saveMany(
    factory(Product::class)->times(10)->make()
);
```

That would use the factory to mock 10 products and create them using the relationship defined on the User model.